# How to listen to events emitted by nested components I do not control?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to use the Vuetify *Selects* component in its ["Autocomplete" version](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/selects#example-5).

One thing I need, however, is to query the request string (which is typd into the form). It is not directly available, but I see in DevTools (Vue tab) that `<v-select>` emits the event `"update:searchInput"` which has this request string in its payload.

I tried to listen to this event in my component (at mount time: `this.$on('update:searchInput', this.querySelections)`) but it looks like that it is just passed to the immediate parent and not above.

**In other words: I have a component which I do not control which emits an event to its parent (which I do not control either) and I do not know how to intercept it in my component.** Is this possible?

For information, the code of the example is below. I believe that It is not that useful, though, as the Vue DevTools tab is not available. It just shows that the only value I can get back directly from the component is `a1`, which is the already-chosen item (and not the request string as it it typed in)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      a1: null,
      states: [
        'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona',
        'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut',
        'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia',
        'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho',
        'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
        'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland',
        'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
        'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York',
        'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio',
        'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico',
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
        'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Island', 'Virginia',
        'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.17.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.17.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card color="grey lighten-4" flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6>
              <v-subheader v-text="'Autocomplete'"></v-subheader>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6>
              <v-select v-bind:items="states" v-model="a1" label="Select" autocomplete></v-select>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [extend](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) the `v-select` component to take a bus prop, onto which you can relay the `update:searchInput` event, so that you can catch it at the top level.

```js
Vue.component('my-select', {
  extends: Vue.component('v-select'),
  props: ['bus'],
  created() {
    this.$on('update:searchInput', (payload) => this.bus.$emit('update:searchInput', payload));
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      a1: null,
      states: [
        'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona',
        'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut',
        'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia',
        'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho',
        'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
        'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland',
        'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
        'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York',
        'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio',
        'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico',
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
        'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Island', 'Virginia',
        'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
      ],
      bus: new Vue()
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.bus.$on('update:searchInput', (payload) => console.log("Got", payload));
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.17.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.17.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card color="grey lighten-4" flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6>
              <v-subheader v-text="'Autocomplete'"></v-subheader>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6>
              <my-select :bus="bus" v-bind:items="states" v-model="a1" label="Select" autocomplete></my-select>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```